# Can't add an event listener to an element from an API

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, addeventlistener

I am building a trivia webapp using an API and i want to add an event listener to the button with the correct answer so that when the user clicks it it will display a message saying they're right and it'll get a new question.
Here's how the code looks:

```
function useApiData(triviaObj) {
  let answers = sortArrayRandomly([
    triviaObj.results[0].correct_answer,
    triviaObj.results[0].incorrect_answers[0],
    triviaObj.results[0].incorrect_answers[1],
    triviaObj.results[0].incorrect_answers[2],
  ]);

  document.querySelector("#category").innerHTML = `Category: ${triviaObj.results[0].category}`;
  document.querySelector("#difficulty").innerHTML = `Difficulty: ${triviaObj.results[0].difficulty}`;
  document.querySelector("#question").innerHTML = `Question: ${triviaObj.results[0].question}`;

  document.querySelector("#answer1").innerHTML = `${answers[0]}`;
  document.querySelector("#answer2").innerHTML = `${answers[1]}`;
  document.querySelector("#answer3").innerHTML = `${answers[2]}`;
  document.querySelector("#answer4").innerHTML = `${answers[3]}`;

  let rightAnswer = triviaObj.results[0].correct_answer;
  rightAnswer.addEventListener("click", correctAnswer);

  console.log(answers);
}

function correctAnswer() {
  alert("correct");
  getTrivia();
}
```

It tells me that the AddEventListener is not a function, how can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly is 'triviaObj.results[0].correct_answer'? Evidently it is not an html element.

Comment: You need to add the event listener to the `#answerX` element that corresponds to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to fill in the answer elements. In that loop you can check if the current answer is the correct answer and add the event listener.

```js
answers.forEach((answer, i) => {
  let button = document.querySelector(`#answer${i+1}`);
  button.innerHTML = answer;
  if (answer == triviaObj.results[0].correct_answer) {
    button.addEventListener("click", correctAnswer);
  } else {
    button.removeEventListener("click", correctAnswer);
  }
});
```

Comment: This works at first but after the a button is the correct answer and it moves on to the next one and the correct answer is on another button, that previous stays "correct" and even if it has the wrong answer it works. How can i remove that "correct state when it moves on to another question?

Comment: Remove the event listener from the other buttons. I've updated the answer.

Comment: A simpler solution would be to add the event listener to all buttons, and have the function check whether their text matches the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Event listeners go on DOM elements, not on pieces of data or other variables. Try finding the correct answer element and attaching the event listener to that:

```
const rightAnswer = triviaObj.results[0].correct_answer;
const matchingAnswer = answers.find((x) => x === rightAnswer);
const rightElement = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="answer"]'))
  .find((el) => el.innerText.includes(rightAnswer))
rightElement.addEventListener("click", correctAnswer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `triviaObj.results[0].correct_answer` is a number representing the correct answer, then:

Replace

```
let rightAnswer = triviaObj.results[0].correct_answer;
```

with

```
let rightAnswer = document.querySelector(`#answer${triviaObj.results[0].correct_answer}`);
```

This is much more simple than Zan Anger's solution.